# meaning of sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was watching an English Movie in which children were searching for jobs, their parent asked one of them:

> How's the job hunt coming ?

Is this sentence correct? Is this same as *"how's the job hunt going on?"*? 
Which sentence is the most appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, and has pretty well the same meaning as "How's the job hunt going?" (I find "going on" slightly less idiomatic, because it implies that the person you are asking has nothing to do with the process).

I think "coming" is slightly friendlier, because it implies that the goal (the job) is something that the speaker is identifying with as well - it is "coming" to us, not just to you. But the difference is very slight.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence

> **How's the job hunt coming**?

is short for

> **How's the job hunt coming** ***along***?

and means the same as

> **How's the job hunt going** ?
>   **How goes the job hunt** ?

**going on** would not be correct since one

> **goes job hunting**

but does not

> **go** ***on*** **job hunting**

The idiom **going on** can be used to ask the current **happening** status of an activity

> What's **going on**?
>
> What's **going on** with the job hunting?
>   Anything **going on** with the job hunting?

**getting on** can be used in the same way, meaning **how far along**

> How's your job hunting **getting on**?
>   How are you **getting on** with the job hunting?

Comment: so when to use "going on" ?